# How to split a table in a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Suppose there is a table in a file:

```
VLan    Interface       State

Vlan1       Fa0/0       Up

Vlan2       Fa0/1       Down

Vlan3       Fa0/3       Up
```

Now I actually need to get the name of the VLan & Interface whose state is up.
But for that I need to split the table at first.
I am new to python and cannot really figure out how to split this table.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the lines from the second line (use **`next`** for that) and check whether state is *Up* and append them (or do whatever you would like to do).

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    next(f)
    l = [line.split()[1] for line in f if line.split()[2] == "Up"]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
['Fa0/0', 'Fa0/3']
```

Btw, even if you don't use `next`, it is fine.

Comment: ```l = []``` is not needed

Comment: @kaidokuuppa Ya, not needed. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your data is contained in `data/table.txt` here the code to extract the content in a structured way, and filter out only the interfaces that are `Up`

```
file_path = 'data/table.txt'

with open(file_path) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# it removes the empty lines
clean_content = [l for l in content if l != '\n']

# remove the line terminator for each line
lines = [l.replace('\n', '') for l in clean_content]

# attributes of the dictionary
dict_attrs = lines[0].split()

interfaces = [dict(zip(dict_attrs, l.split())) for l in lines[1:]]

interfaces_up = [i for i in interfaces if i['State'] == 'Up']
```

Result: `[{'VLan': 'Vlan1', 'Interface': 'Fa0/0', 'State': 'Up'}, {'VLan': 'Vlan3', 'Interface': 'Fa0/3', 'State': 'Up'}]`